# cv::VideoCapture::get() does not return actual width and height

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, video-capture

I'm using OpenCV (v4.5.4) `VideoCapture` class on Ubuntu 22.04 to read from a webcam.  Everything seems to work.

But some of the methods are returning conflicting information, and I'm hoping someone can shed some light.

Camera is initialized like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
if (not cap.isOpened())
{
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to open the webcam");
}
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, 30.0);
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640.0);
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480.0);
```

Then frames are read with this:

```
cv::Mat frame;
cap >> frame;
```

And when I output the size of the frame:

```
std::cout << "frame size: " << frame.size() << std::endl;
```

As expected, this prints out `[640 x 480]`.

But here comes the strange part.  If I query the `cap` object, I get different dimensions:

```
const auto width    = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
const auto height   = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
const auto fps      = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS);
const auto size     = cv::Size(width, height);
std::cout << "Cap says " << size << " @ " << fps << " FPS." << std::endl;
```

This prints out `[1280 x 720] @ 10 FPS`.

Shouldn't this print out 640x480?  Is there something special I need to do to get accurate values from the `cap` object?

Comment: if you can reproduce this on latest release, it's worth a bug report. you might wanna do that with `opencv-python` because that's trivial to install, while C++ stuff rarely is. before creating a new issue, please spend a moment checking for the issue already having been filed.